# Can't log into mysql server root user using password?

Tags: mysql

```
root@DS-S007:/etc/dspam# mysql -u root –ppassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@DS-S007:/etc/dspam#
```

I clearly specified a password. Why does is still say NO?

I have also tried the variation mysql -u root –p. Which usually works for me.

("password" is not what I'm actually typing.)

Comment: Try using only -u root -p ... that is no "password" after -p.

Comment: I've tried that as well. It didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same error? Can you log in as a different user?

Comment: I don't have any others yet. but it always says "NO" regardless of the user name.

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Have you set the root password yet? If not, then you need to login with 'mysql -u root mysql'

Comment: yes i set the password already. I just ran "mysql_secure_installation" to make sure its installed. It took my password. Can password logins be disabled?

Comment: Yes, but you need to log in as root to do that. See if any info on this page gets you anywhere: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-denied.html

Comment: yes thats correct. the root password works during installation, but not login.

Comment: Thank you for the attachment. I have searched it, but it did not provide any clues.

Comment: Try using the long form of the command and report back.  (For example, [`mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html).)

Comment: wow HopelessN00b! That actually worked! Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HopelessN00b suggested i try the long form of the command. This worked correctly. What a weird issue!

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=mypass mydb
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that you've not put a space between -p and your password? `(using password: NO)`

Failing that, have you run the MySQL setup scripts? You may want to do that, since you're on Debian it should be:

`# mysql_install_db`

and running the security script would be

`# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: yes I know there is no space. I have tried it both ways. Yes I have run and rerun the setup scripts. Any other ideas?

Comment: Personally, I would try purging & reinstalling mysql (`# apt-get purge mysql-server`) and running the setup scripts again. Since your connection is definitely making to the server, the only thing that could be wrong is bad credentials.